# NSURLRequest: Always getting NSCachedURLResponse back.

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I'm using AfNetworking, I make a call for new data but I keep getting the cached result back. So if I'm in a VC that's shows the data, pop back to the root and change data on my server, I then wait 30sec and when I push back into the VC I'll see the the old data. If I hit the URL in a browser I see the correct data. If I re-run the app I will see the changes to the data.

My response from my server sends back cache control header: Cache-Control:max-age=10, public

From what I can tell is that I always always get a NSCachedURLResponse back and that the cache is not listening to my cache-controll policy.

In my AppDelegate I set my SharedURLCache:

```
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:8 * 1024 * 1024 diskCapacity:8 * 1024 * 1024 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

How I set the URLRequest:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

I do nothing else involving NSURLCache.

Any ideas?

BooRanger

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is exactly what I'd expect from the code you've posted. Have you tried using `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` instead of `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`? According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy) `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` means:

> Specifies that the caching logic defined in the protocol
>   implementation, if any, is used for a particular URL load request.
>   This is the default policy for URL load requests.

So if you want it to always load from the server, you should use `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` which is described as:

> Specifies that not only should the local cache data be ignored, but
>   that proxies and other intermediates should be instructed to disregard
>   their caches so far as the protocol allows.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I set NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy it will use my headerField "Cache-Control" to set the cache.

Comment: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData doesn't seem to work either, so maybe I'm missing something elsewhere... Cheers

Comment: Is more than 10 seconds passing?

Comment: The fact that `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` is not working is kind of surprising to me. If you use NSURLConnection explicitly instead of AFNetworking, do you still have the problem?

Comment: Then what is caching for anymore, if you ignore it?